# Getting hp3520e to work with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: hp

How do I get my new hp 3520e to print from my desktop using Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: How are you intending to connect this to your computer: USB or via LAN?

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't working "out of the box" "automagically" then I guess you will have to install the drivers from http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=2020&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=5162506

Please edit your question if you don't know how to install it.